# Parsing or autoboxing or unboxing

Tags: java, parsing, autoboxing, unboxing

So I already read what parsing is in the threads here, but wouldnt this be autoboxing or unboxing because it goes from an `int` to an `Integer`? 
This is the sentence

> When an integer is added to an array list declared as `ArrayList<Integer>`, Java performs what?

Answer (score 1):

The automatic conversion happening here:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = ...
int value = 42;
list.add(value);
```

is called "autoboxing" (or "boxing conversion"): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

```
int value2 = list.get(0);
```

would be "unboxing" because the `Integer` from the lists is converted to an `int`.

Parsing happens only when you read something out of text, like `Integer.parseInt("42")`.